# How to pass an enum class which is inside another class's function by reference?

Tags: c++, class, oop, enums, member

I am still fairly new to C++, so sorry if the code is a bit amateurish, that might be the source of the problem.

I've spent some time searching this site and across the web. There are plenty of examples using `enum`s (not `enum class`) and also of using `enum`s and `enum`s class outside of classes, but didn't really find anything useful for my particular scenario, see below. Of course, I may have seen the answer, but my C++ is not advanced enough yet to recognize it.

Basically I want to pass 2 "state" `enum`s classes into a method, in a different class from the ones in which the enums classes are defined, and then change the state of the second enum class based on the value in the first enum class. These enum classes are defined inside a class which contains a pointer to the second class in which the method is defined. Class declarations are in header files and defined in separate .cpp files which include the relevant headers. See the detailed code and errors below.

Hoping someone can help me interpret the error messages at the end and figure out how to achieve this.

**`main.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "firstfile.h"

int main() {
    FirstFile firstobject;
    firstobject.Function1();
}
```

Basically, I've got 2 `enum classe`s inside following class.

**`firstfile.h`**

```
#include "secondfile.h"

class FirstFile 
{
protected:
    SecondFile secondobject;

public:
    enum class enum1 {
        Option1,
        Option2
    } enumIn = enum1::Option1;

    enum class enum2 {
        Option3,
        Option4
    } enumInOut = enum2::Option3;
    // Methods
protected:
public:
    void Function1();
};
```

**`firstfile.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "firstfile.h"

void FirstFile::Function1()
{
    std::cout << "Before the function call enumIn = Option 1 and enumInOut = Option3 " << std::endl;
    secondobject.function2(enumIn, enumInOut);

    if (enumInOut == enum2::Option4) {
        std::cout << "After the function call enumInOut = Option 4" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (enumInOut == enum2::Option3) {
        std::cout << "After the function call enumInOut = Option 3" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "enumInOut didn't match either Option 3 or Option 4" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The header file, where most of the errors occur.

**`secondfile.h`**

```
#include "firstfile.h"

class SecondFile 
{   
public:
    void function2(const enum1& enumIn, enum2& enumInOut);
};
```

Finally, here is the method in class2 that is being called that should update enum2 based on the value of enum1.

**`secondfile.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "firstfile.h"
#include "secondfile.h"

void SecondFile::function2(const enum1& enumIn, enum2& enumInOut) 
{
    if (enumIn == FirstFile::enum1::Option1) {
        enumInOut = FirstFile::enum2::Option4;
    }
}
```

---

The errors are:

```
firstfile.cpp
\secondfile.h(16, 28) : error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed.Note : C++ does not support default - int
\secondfile.h(16, 28) : error C2143 : syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
\firstfile.cpp(8, 42) : error C2660 : 'SecondFile::function2' : function does not take 2 arguments
\secondfile.h(16, 7) : message: see declaration of 'SecondFile::function2'

Main.cpp
\secondfile.h(16, 28) : error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed.Note : C++ does not support default - int
\secondfile.h(16, 28) : error C2143 : syntax error : missing ',' before '&'

secondfile.cpp
\secondfile.h(16, 28) : error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed.Note : C++ does not support default - int
\secondfile.h(16, 28) : error C2143 : syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
\secondfile.cpp(5, 39) : error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed.Note : C++ does not support default - int
\secondfile.cpp(5, 39) : error C2143 : syntax error : missing ',' before '&'

\secondfile.cpp(6, 6) : error C2065 : 'enumIn' : undeclared identifier
\secondfile.cpp(7, 3) : error C2065 : 'enumInOut' : undeclared identifier
```

Hope this all makes sense and look forward to any insights to help understand the cause of the errors and how I might be able to resolve them.
It's probably related to scope, but hoping to learn from this experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

- You have **[circular dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency#:%7E:text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20a%20circular,also%20known%20as%20mutually%20recursive.)**, since you add the header of each classes to each other's header files. You can solve it via pointers members. Make the class member `secondobject` in the class `FirstFile` as a pointer, and provide a forward declaration in the header (i.e. in `firstfile.h`) for `SecondFile`.
- Secondly, you need to specify the `enum1` and `enum2` from which class/ scope it is. You can use the [`using` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) for this, and enums will be available for the entire class `SecondFile`'s scope.

That means, you need something like: **([See Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3sQ4L6aItyidHtQW))**

**`firstfile.h`**

```
class SecondFile; // forward declaration

class FirstFile 
{
protected:
    SecondFile* secondobject{ nullptr }; // or smart pointers

public:
    // ...enums and functions
};
```

**`firstfile.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "secondfile.h"

void FirstFile::Function1() 
{
    // ...other code
    if(secondobject)
    secondobject->function2(enumIn, enumInOut);
    //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^

}
```

**`secondfile.h`**

```
#include "firstfile.h"

class SecondFile 
{    
public:
    using enum1 = FirstFile::enum1;  // specify from where the enums are
    using enum2 = FirstFile::enum2;
    void function2(const enum1& enumIn, enum2& enumInOut);
     
    // ...other codes
};
```

**`secondfile.cpp`**

```
#include "secondfile.h"

void SecondFile::function2(const enum1& enumIn, enum2& enumInOut) 
{
    if (enumIn == enum1::Option1) {
        enumInOut = enum2::Option4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick reply and comprehensive answer. Looks like there were a couple of basic mistakes (circular dependencies) and lack of forward declarations. Thought the scope of the enums was part of the problem, glad I was right with that. The code you provided works but as secondobject is never created the function is never called. Tried creating it but getting an error around not getting a pointer to class. Could you add that line to the code?? Will spend some time taking this apart to understand how it works. Many thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly where I put my code to create secondobject but I didn't use the Curley braces, not  sure I've ever seen that before. That may be why I got the pointer conversion error. Also why does the forward declaration get round my scoping problem, is it to do with the different translation units for the 2 files?? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the various links, very useful. I've accepted your answer.